# IIS 10 HTTP response 404 for JSON files

Tags: json, http-status-code-404, iis-10

I have a JSON file that will not serve from IIS 10. When I browse to it it always returns a 404.0 error. I've checked the IIS Logs and the request is for the correct path. The file is in the specified location in the web directory structure. The MIME Type .json has been added as application/json. I did this 2 different ways, using the IIS Management Console, and by adding it to the Web Config using a remove followed by the tag to add it.

I have also added other file types, PNG, html right next to it in the same directory with the same permissions. They load just fine. The JSON file is named translation-en.json.

I've scoured stackoverflow for similar issues and tried everything I can find. I've worked with the vendor for the component that needs to load the file using fetch. Tried all of their suggestions.

My most recent attempt was to install Failed-Request Tracing and configure it to log ALL responses 400-999 with Verbose output and I get nothing at all. If I can get that working I might be able to learn something. But no luck.

Fiddler just shows a simple 404 Response from the server.

I am using the MS URL Rewrite module to handle routing. It is configured as follows:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Assets" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|js|json|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Interestingly, if I turn Directory Browsing on I am able to see the files:

[image: With Directory Browsing enabled]

Clicking on test.png works fine. Clicking on any other .json results in a 404 error.

I'm at a complete standstill. Help?

Comment: Will there be a 404 if I directly access the json file without using the URL Rewrite module?

Comment: Thank you @DingPeng. Removing the URL Rewrite config fixes the problem. I will research the configuration documentation to determine why. Thanks for helping me get to the cause!

Comment: Solution was to change the order of the URL Rewrite pattern to match json before js.

Answer (score 2):

This was solved by changing the matching pattern for static content in the URL so json comes before js.

Broken config: `([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|js|json|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))`

Working config: `([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|json|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))`

Complete rewrite config section:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Assets" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|json|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also the staticContent tag which can be used like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension="json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```